# AutoIncrement of Multiple columns in indexeddb

Tags: auto-increment, indexeddb

Does any one know - how we can specify autoincrement for two columns in indexeddb.

I know - we can specify autoincremnt for one column while creating table like this -

```
var objectStore = thisDb.createObjectStore("note", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement:true });
```

but not able to find how we can do the same for multiple columns. Also as far as i know - we cant get the value of autoincrement.  The value will be autoincremented & added when we will insert the data. So if i can get the autoincrement value somehow, that would the solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create two auto-incremented properties in a store. That feature is only available for the property defined as the key path.

You can easily get the auto-incremented value. The value is provided as the `result` of the `put` or `add` request that inserted a new object.

For example:

```
function addThing(db, thing) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let id = undefined;

    const transaction = db.transaction('things', 'readwrite');
    const store = transaction.objectStore('things');

    // wait to resolve the promise until the transaction is completed
    // so that we do not prematurely pretend the operation succeeded. resolve 
    // to the value of the new id
    transaction.oncomplete = event => resolve(id);

    transaction.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);

    // store.add also works here
    const request = store.put(thing);

    // listen for the add event and grab the value of the new id
    // that indexedDB generated and store it in the id variable
    request.onsuccess = event => id = event.target.result;
  });
}


async function doSomething() {
  const something = {bar: 'baz'};

  const db = await open(...);
  const id = await addThing(db, something);
  db.close();

  something.id = id;
  console.log(something);
}
```

Comment: ok, Thanks Josh. Can we get the autoincrement value before doing any operation - add, put etc. So that i can use the autoincrement value for other columns which needs to be autoincremented ?

Comment: Pretty sure the only way to get this value is to issue a put/add request.

Comment: Correct, the generated key is not available until the request has succeeded. The reason is that the number isn't known before then. You can invoke db.transaction() twice against the same store and start issuing put()s against both, although none of the requests from the second transaction will even start to run until the first transaction completes. Therefore, the generated keys for those requests depend entirely on what happens with the first transaction (which might succeed, abort, etc). 

Instead of relying on the built-in key generator mechanism, you can implement one yourself.